# How i can make get method in if statment without errors

Tags: java, phantomjs

i want to use ids value in other class that inherit from this class

```
if (title.equals("***")) {
                String ids = driver.findElement(By.name("Idsession")).getAttribute("value");
            }
```

i tried to make a get method so the code will be

```
 if (title.equals("***")) {
                String ids = driver.findElement(By.name("Idsession")).getAttribute("value");
public String getID() {
                        return ids;
                    }
                }
```

but i'm getting errors

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved
>   compilation problems:     Syntax error on token(s), misplaced
>   construct(s)  Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
>
> at Login.initialize(Login.java:275)     at Login.(Login.java:108)
>     at Login$1.run(Login.java:91)   at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

full code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
//import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
/*
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
*/
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
//import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
//import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders.TextFieldBorder;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
//import java.awt.Point;
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream;
//import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;

import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;


//import java.io.File;
//import java.io.IOException;
//import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
//import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
//import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
//import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
//import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;



public class Login extends JFrame {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField daten;
    private JLabel background;
    private JLabel cinlabel;
    private JLabel title_1;
    private JLabel datalabel;
    private JTextField code;
    private JLabel codelabel;
    private JPasswordField CIN;
    private JLabel lblVersionBeta;
    public WebDriver driver;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            // body of main method goes here, including any other error handling
          } catch (Throwable t) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, t.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + t.getMessage());
            throw t; // don't suppress Throwable
          }

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Login window = new Login();
                    //window.frame.setUndecorated(true);
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        //PropertyConfigurator.configure("C:\\Users\\MJ\\eclipse-workspace\\FindMyResults\\src\\log4j.properties");
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public Login() throws IOException {
        initialize();

    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    private void initialize() throws IOException {


        frame = new JFrame();
        //java.awt.Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        //int w=screenSize.width;
        //int h=screenSize.height;
        //if (w==1366 && h==768) {
            frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1015, 600);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        //}else {
        //  frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1024, 768);
        //  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //  frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        //}


        /*java.awt.Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
        setVisible(true);*/

        codelabel = new JLabel("Code de s\u00E9curit\u00E9 \t");
        codelabel.setFont(new Font("Dubai Medium", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        codelabel.setBounds(764, 279, 182, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(codelabel);

        cinlabel = new JLabel("CIN ou Identifiant DGCI ");
        cinlabel.setFont(new Font("Dubai Medium", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        cinlabel.setBounds(574, 74, 294, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(cinlabel);

        datalabel = new JLabel("Date de naissance (jj/mm/aaaa)\t");
        datalabel.setFont(new Font("Dubai Medium", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        datalabel.setBounds(574, 183, 294, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(datalabel);
        URL title =getClass().getResource("/images/title.png");

        CIN = new JPasswordField();
        CIN.setBounds(574, 99, 396, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(CIN);

        daten = new JTextField();
        daten.setBackground(new Color(248, 248, 255));
        daten.setBounds(574, 208, 396, 50);
        daten.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        daten.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        daten.setColumns(10);
        frame.getContentPane().add(daten);




/*
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        } };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        try {
            editorPane.setPage(url);
            //editorPane.scrollToReference(reference);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Attempted to read a bad URL: " + url);
        }

        */
        //URL browser =getClass().getResource("/browser/phantomjs.exe");
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "phantomjs.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();

        //driver.manage().Window.Size = new Size(1920, 1080);
        driver.get("https://www4.inscription.tn/ORegMx/servlet/AuthentificationEtud?ident=cin");
        String title1=driver.getTitle();
        if (!(title1.equals("Site de l'inscription universitaire en ligne"))) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Verifiez votre connexion internet");
            driver.quit();

        }
        WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@rowspan='2']"));

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // Get entire page screenshot
        File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        BufferedImage  fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);

        // Get the location of element on the page
        org.openqa.selenium.Point point = ele.getLocation();

        // Get width and height of the element
        int eleWidth = ele.getSize().getWidth();
        int eleHeight = ele.getSize().getHeight();

        // Crop the entire page screenshot to get only element screenshot
        BufferedImage eleScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(),
            eleWidth, eleHeight);
        ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "png", screenshot);

        // Copy the element screenshot to disk
        File screenshotLocation = new File("temp\\captcha.png");
        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, screenshotLocation); 


        JLabel captcha = new JLabel("");
        captcha.setIcon(new ImageIcon("temp\\captcha.png"));
        captcha.setBounds(574, 304, 182, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(captcha);




        JButton valider = new JButton("Valider");
        valider.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {




                WebElement c = driver.findElement(By.name("cin"));
                WebElement d = driver.findElement(By.id("dn"));
                WebElement cap = driver.findElement(By.name("cincap"));

                String myPass=String.valueOf(CIN.getPassword());
                String date = daten.getText();
                String capp = code.getText();

                // fill the fields
                c.sendKeys(myPass);
                d.sendKeys(date);
                cap.sendKeys(capp);

                // button valider
                cap.submit();



                // check the title of the page
                String title=driver.getTitle();
                if (title.equals("Dashboard - Inscription universitaire en ligne")) {
                    WebElement msg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[2]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/p[1]"));
                    String name=msg.getAttribute("innerText");
                    //System.out.println(error);
                    String ids = driver.findElement(By.name("Idsession")).getAttribute("value");
                    private String getID() 
                    {
                        return ids;
                    }
                //  String cookie=ids.getAttribute("innerText");
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ids,"Bienvenue", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,name,"Bienvenue", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                //System.out.println("Bienvenue");   //modify to new frame soon
                    frame.dispose();
                    Accueil bien=new Accueil();
                    bien.setVisible(true);
                // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
                else {
                    WebElement msg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/blockquote[1]/div[1]/font[1]"));
                    String error=msg.getAttribute("innerText");
                    //System.out.println(error);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,error);



                    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@rowspan='2']"));
                    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    // Get entire page screenshot
                    File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                    BufferedImage fullImg = null;
                    try {
                        fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Get the location of element on the page
                    org.openqa.selenium.Point point = ele.getLocation();

                    // Get width and height of the element
                    int eleWidth = ele.getSize().getWidth();
                    int eleHeight = ele.getSize().getHeight();

                    // Crop the entire page screenshot to get only element screenshot
                    BufferedImage eleScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(),
                        eleWidth, eleHeight);
                    try {
                        ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "png", screenshot);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Copy the element screenshot to disk
                    File screenshotLocation = new File("temp\\captcha.png");
                    try {
                        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, screenshotLocation);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }       



                    ImageIcon img=new ImageIcon("temp\\captcha.png");
                    img.getImage().flush();
                    captcha.setIcon(img);


                }


            }

        });



        valider.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        valider.setBounds(686, 462, 162, 32);
        frame.getContentPane().add(valider);

        code = new JTextField();
        code.setBackground(new Color(248, 248, 255));
        code.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        code.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        code.setColumns(10);
        code.setBounds(764, 304, 206, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(code);

                title_1 = new JLabel("");
                title_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(title));
                title_1.setBounds(45, 138, 440, 90);
                frame.getContentPane().add(title_1);

        lblVersionBeta = new JLabel("Version Beta");
        lblVersionBeta.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        lblVersionBeta.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblVersionBeta.setBounds(49, 201, 104, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblVersionBeta);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground( new Color(0, 0, 0, 90) );
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 511, 735);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);




        background = new JLabel("");
        //BufferedImage bg = ImageIO.read(new File("./resources/img/AnimationV.gif"));

        URL bg =getClass().getResource("/images/AnimationV.gif");

        // getClass().getResource("resources/img/AnimationV.gif");
        //Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);
        //java.io.InputStream image = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream( "resources/img/AnimationV.gif" );

        background.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bg));
        background.setBounds(0, 0, 1006, 724);
        frame.getContentPane().add(background);



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to do it by storing the output to a txt file then use it whenever i need, thanks @shahril772 for help

Answer (score 0):

You **cant** create a method inside a method.
You must declare getIds() **outside** **the block**
like this...

```
           public class name {

     private String ids = "";

    public static  void main(String arg[]){

       if (title.equals("***")) {
      // reinitialize id  when title is  equals '***'
    ids =driver.findElement(
By.name("Idsession")) .getAttribute("value");
  }

      String newThing = getID();
      //use it
      }

      // method declaration here

          public String getID() {
            return ids; 
           } 

   }
```

Comment: but it saying "the value of the local variable is not used" so i think the get method not using the ids variable i need

Comment: please check the full code and tell me where i put the codes exactly

Comment: the code need to be executed when i hit the button that's why i didn't put it the main

Comment: and what newThing variable do?

Comment: just put the if-statement where the onhit event do....and the newThing variable just for example....

Comment: yes, the if-statement is in the "onhit event" but the get method still didn't get the ids variable that is in the if statement, but it get the declared variable wich is an empty String

Comment: that mean your title is not equals '***', so the id is not changed

Comment: i don't think so, i didn't run the software yet, in the line 

`ids =driver.findElement(By.name("Idsession")) .getAttribute("value");`

 it say "the value of the local variable is not used" and the get method say "ids cannot be resolved to a variable